# Error: not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: firebase, command-prompt

I'm following instructions [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/delete-unused-accounts-cron/README.md) to set up a sample:

I'm at this step:

> Setup the sample with your project firebase use --add and follow the
>   instructions.

But, I get the following error in command prompt:
[image]

I'm sure there's an easy fix, I'm just new.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. First install nodejs at your system using https://nodejs.org/en/download/
2. Then using npm package manager which comes with nodejs; install firebase with the help of this url https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-tools

Comment: Ok, I'll try that & let you know.

Comment: Very nice. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Awesome, nice to hear that!!

Comment: I had it installed already but reinstalling the latest version after installing firebase worked.

Answer (score 4):

As Lalit said install first node.js then make sure that make sure that this went well by typing

```
node -v
```

and

```
npm -v
```

if these two tests went well install firebase as the following:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

and since you are new please try copy past commands until you get used to them.