# How to change the directory of my installed firebase?

Tags: node.js, windows, firebase, firebase-cli

I have installed firebase by running `npm install -g firebase-tools` and other command, but somehow I still cannot run any firebase command in my ionic project directory as a error message will show

> 'firebase' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.

Turnout the firebase has been install to other directory instead of my project directory. That's why I cannot run firebase command in my project directory. I can only run firebase command in the installed directory.

Anyone know how to install firebase to a specific project directory? I have done some research. Some of the solution is to modify code in firebase.json file, but my firebase.json file is empty and I tried to change the code like this but it still does work.

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "C:/Users/CJ/desktop/fyp"
  }
}
```

### --

--
`npm install firebase-tools`does not work for me,this is the result:

```
C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\fyp\tools\functions>npm install firebase-tools
npm WARN firebase-functions@3.3.0 requires a peer of firebase-admin@^8.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.2 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ firebase-tools@7.10.0
updated 1 package and audited 6497 packages in 54.671s

1 package is looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 200 vulnerabilities (122 moderate, 78 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\fyp\tools\functions>firebase
'firebase' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44603218/error-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: It does not answer my question,the answer is like how to install firebase CLI but I am already installed it and I need to change the directory where it has been installed or else I am unable to run any firebase command in my project directory.

Comment: It looks like there is something wrong with your node installation, or your PATH isn't configured correctly for global installations.

Comment: yeah I think so ,my global installation is C:/program files/git/usr/local, I forgot what command I typed to make the PATH become like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `npm install -g`, it is NPM that determines where the package/tool is installed. Firebase has no control over that.

If you want to install the Firebase CLI in the local project direction, run the `npm install` command with the `-g` option:

```
npm install firebase-tools
```

Comment: I think you're struggling with how NPM works in general. I recommend taking a look at Firebase's recently released [standalone binary version of the CLI for Windows](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#install-cli-windows), which precisely tries to address some of these path related problems.

Answer (score 0):

use npx firebase login
and install firebase tools without -g